# Why are my potato leaf edges white?

Tags: diagnosis, plant-health, potatoes

They sprouted out of the ground this way, but I've noticed more white in the past few days. They were planted around 2 weeks ago.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is probably an attack by the potato flea beetle. Deficiency or simple necrosis (leaf tissue death by mechanical means) would be more yellow, brown or black; the white is distinctive. The beetles chew out the green layer inside the leaf and do so in a spotty fashion leaving circular patches, so the leaf surfaces remain but the green is gone, leaving a white appearance.

More detail on potato flea beetle in this [University of Maryland Extension IPM paper](https://extension.umd.edu/learn/insect-pest-management-potato).